# Emitter Collision not working?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a question about the collision I am making for my emitter to spawn. When the collision happens, the app crashes. but from the research I've been doing, I don't see what's wrong.

Collision:

```
if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 3 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 3 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1{
    print("END GAME")
    let dieexplostionNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explode")
    player.addChild(dieexplostionNode!)
}
```

Am I missing something for the emitter to spawn? Every time it collides it crashes.

Comment: dieeexplostionNode is probably nil if this is the code which crashes. Use if let and check if there is an Explode.sks file in your project.

Comment: Wait, I need a SKS file for this? I thought the particle systems were scnp? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How would I go about adding the SCNP files to get it to spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment on the answer above I think an Action is what you need.

```
if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 3 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 3 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1{
    print("END GAME")

dieexplostionNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks"){
dieexplostionNode.targetNode = self 
//dieexplostionNode.position = player.position - no need for this!

// add 3 actions
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
let addExplosion = SKAction.run {
    self.player.addChild(dieexplostionNode!)
}
let removeExplosion = SKAction.run {
        dieexplostionNode?.removeFromParent()
 }

// put them in a sequence.
let seq = SKAction.sequence([addExplosion,wait,removeExplosion])

// run the sequence
self.run(seq)

}
```

this will add the dieexplostionNode to the player. then wait for 2 seconds. then remove the dieexplostionNode

Comment: Perfect! I forgot i can use a sequence to do this. Thank you very much with the help!

Comment: No problem. if you feel that the explosion disappears to abruptly you can add other actions in the sequence. like SKAction.fadeOut. or set the birthrate to 0 some moments before removing the emitter :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you confusing SceneKit with SpriteKit?
SCN files/Abreviations are used in SceneKit
If you want to add a SpriteKit Particle Emitter file.
File -> New -> IOS/OSX -> Resource -> SpriteKit Particle File

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty confused what the difference was. How would I go about displaying the emitter then removing the SKNode? I have the following but before it is triggered it removes the SKNode.               if let dieexplostionNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks"){
            dieexplostionNode.targetNode = self
            dieexplostionNode.position = player.position
            player.addChild(dieexplostionNode)

Comment: It's confusing what you are trying to do.  Trying your code the problem I found is it's doesn't show.  I think that is a good place to start.  The problem appears to be you are setting the position to player.position and then adding it to the player.  This is adding the position from the scene compared  to the player.  If you remove the statement dieexplostionNode.position = player.position it will place it where the player is by default.

Comment: @DonFirth thats a good point. By just adding the EmittrNode to the player the position will be default at 0.0 in the player coordinate space. Setting the position of the emitter to something else then 0.0 will offset the position inside the player coordinate space. In other words. The position of a node is always relative to the parent node